# Cannot export all rows from foxpro to excel?

Tags: excel, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to export tables from foxpro to excel, But it didn't export all rows from foxpro.
I have 82377 rows in forxpro table, after I exported to excel, I found only 65534 rows in excel. I tried another foxpro table which had 67548 rows, but after exported, I found the same as the old one 65534 rows in excel and other tables and got the same result.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Foxpro 9.0

Comment: what Excel version are you using? prior 2007 that 65K was the limit now is 1 million

Comment: @Eric is right. If you want to export more than 65534 rows, you should use Excel 2007 or later.

Comment: oh, i see, I'm using excel 2007, but the foxpro tool support only Excel 3.0, 4.0 and 5.0, i used "excel 5.0" format that why it can store only 65k, thank you both guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct... VFP never expanded the export to excel format past the 64k limit of earlier Excel files.

Copy out via CSV and it will dump them all... Excel will still be able to read CSV file format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using COPY TO for doing this export. Sine COPY TO always creates files in the Excel 5.0 Format there will be no way to export more than 65534 rows.
But if Excel and the VFP OleDB-Driver are installed on the system the export runs you can use the API for doing this.
Just create in your program a free table with only the data you want to export. Then open Excel by using the API and fetch the data from the table you just created before via OleDB!
On this way you are able to get as many rows as the installed version of Excel supports. So if  Excel 2007 or 2010 is installed you are able to export your 82377 rows!